# Jenkins can't find binary in PATH and doesn't appear to inherit from Linux

Tags: linux, jenkins, rhel

I've tried everything for this an it's exhausted my knowledge.  I'm trying to get Jenkins to use the Path from Linux and it's not working it seems.

Running Jenkins on RHEL Linux and Jenkins runs using the 'jenkins' user:
[image]

If I sudo su as the 'jenkins' user, I can see items like Blaze and Firefox on the Path:
[image]

(Both Jenkins and the server have been restarted multiple times since these have been on the path)

If I `firefox -V` while in a `jenkins` user bash, it works fine.   In a Jenkins job that attempts to use the Firefox driver, it errors with the following:

```
Cannot find firefox binary in PATH. Make sure firefox is installed. OS appears to be: LINUX
```

In the System Info, it has `PATH=/sbin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin`

```
Running as SYSTEM
[EnvInject] - Loading node environment variables.
```

The settings for the nodes are default, which I understand means it should inherit from linux
[image]

I also made a job that runs the following:

```
whoami
echo $PATH
firefox -V
```

This returns:

```
+ whoami
jenkins
+ echo /sbin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin
/sbin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin
+ firefox -V
/tmp/jenkins4835013049839580673.sh: line 4: firefox: command not found
```

No matter what I try, I can't seem to get Jenkins to use the 'correct' Path value.  Is there something I'm missing, or is it as confusing as I am feeling?

Additional Stuff:

- Adding a symlink into /usr/bin also doesn't work for some reason.
- I can't add them as "Environment Variables" within the Jenkins config as it seems to break the pipeline jobs that don't need the additional binaries.

Can anyone help?

Comment: This happened to me a while ago and the reason was, the default shell for the jenkins user was not the one all other users had. Try echo "$SHELL" and see if that is what you expect. Other things to try: start firefox with the full path, insert the PATH in the environment (and export it), start it within a script where you define the shell

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  Unfortunately both the job and everything on CLI show `/bin/bash` as the shell so far.  The other items are larger changes that I'm looking to implement for now. 
It was working previously, it just seems like an OS update has broken it

Comment: What about starting firefox as "/opt/firefox/firefox -V". That works, right?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and could not execute my grails binary from jenkins, as it was added "programmatically" when i started my terminal, which did not apply to Jenkins. My solution was simply to symlink the grails binary to `/usr/local/bin` which was available in `$PATH` from Jenkins.

Symlink using: `sudo ln -s /home/jenkins/.sdkman/candidates/grails/5.0.1/bin/grails /usr/local/bin`

Comment: works on me too.